# What happens to the Fates card from the Deck of Many Things if not used when drawn?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I just read through the possibilities of the [Deck of Many Things](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things), and the Fates card brings to me a question.

Here's the effect of the Fates card:

> ***The Fates.*** Reality's fabric unravels and spins anew, allowing you to avoid or erase one event as if it never happened. You can use the card's magic as soon as you draw the card or at any other time before you die.

It is also said about the Deck of Many Things that:

> Once a card is drawn, it fades from existence. Unless the card is the Fool or the Jester, the card reappears in the deck, making it possible to draw the same card twice.

**If I draw the Fates card, but decide to use it later, what happens exactly to the card?**

Here the two possibilities I have in mind about this:

- The card fades away and come back into the deck, but I still can use the magic that was embedded into it. I guess there's a caveat with this possibility, as this could let me draw it again and let me get a pretty high number of "Fates uses" stock.
- I keep the card, like in my pocket, then when I decide to use its effect it fades and reappears in the deck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## You don't keep the card, so you can in theory stockpile Fates cards

The Fates card description says:

> You can use the **card's *magic*** as soon as you draw the card or at any other time before you die.

It says you use the card's *magic*, not the card itself. In other words, the card itself will fade, as per all cards as specified by your other quote, but the *magic* from this card stays with you.

When I say "it stays with you", I mean that it bestows the ability to undo an event onto you; I don't believe this is intended to make the card useless to anyone else until you use this magic, so if someone else draws the Fates card before you use yours, they still get it's magic themselves too. You can think of it as being like Bardic Inspiration but without a time limit (except death, I guess).

So this means if *you* draw it again, then I believe you can effectively "stockpile" uses of The Fates card, as you suspected. I don't think the rules for combining effects applies here as it's not like you have multiple magic items, since you don't keep the card itself. Also remember that the Deck of Many Things is a powerful game-breaking magic item with massive potential risks for drawing *any* cards, so it's not that surprising that this is a possible outcome.

Comment: Why do you think the rules on stacking game effects wouldn't apply, they apply to all effects of the same name

Comment: @Medix2 I'm not sure those rules would apply since you don't have multiple magic items (i.e. multiple The Fates cards) on your pesron, there aren't multiple spells cast on you or anything similar; the card seems to function more like having a boon bestowed upon you (not an "Epic Boon", I just mean boon in the normal sense of the word). At least, that's how I understand it.